# How to setup testing environment for local HTTPS website?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualbox, localhost

I'm developing a web application on a local Ubuntu machine. Some IE8 users have problems with Javascript when the application is loaded over SSL.

To debug this issue, I need to reproduce the problem. So I have installed Virtual Box with Windows XP and IE8. On the Ubuntu host, Apache serves the web application on `127.0.0.1:80` and `:443`. In the Windows `hosts` file I configured testdomain.com as the domain for 127.0.0.1.

Unsecure HTTP requests to testdomain.com in both the host and the guest return the application response well. Secure HTTPS requests on the host result in an security warning in the browser as expected.

But secure HTTPS requests in the client result in `Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage` because of connection problems. How do I fix this?

Comment: Post all of your sites-enabled.

Comment: MAybe your java scripts are hardcoded into pages via http links, so when users try to load page on https, page fetches JS from http links, which IE8 blocks.